# recaptcha being overridden by CSS style

Tags: css, recaptcha

I'm trying to insert recaptcha into a form on my website.

My CSS is overriding the style of the repaptcha widget and making it look awful..

I've narrowed it down to the body div styles below that alter the way recaptcha appears:

```
#body #content div {
    width :960px;
    background :transparent url("../images/bg-content-bottom.png");
    background-position :center bottom;
    background-repeat :no-repeat;
    padding-bottom :22px;
}
#body #content div div {
    width :860px;
    padding :10px 50px 20px 50px;
    background :transparent url("../images/bg-content.png");
    background-position :center center;
    background-repeat :repeat-y;
}
```

How can i make these stop altering the way the recaptcha appears?

Thank you very much for your time,
James

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: can you fiddle it @jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using global selectors like this is not good practice for this reason, your `div` selector is not specific enough and so the styles are being inherited by the captcha code.

See here for some tips on writing better CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS

You should be more specific with your style selectors and put classes on your child elements like this:

```
#body #content .container {
    width: 960px;
    background: transparent url("../images/bg-content-bottom.png");
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 22px;
}

#body #content .container .pageContent {
    width: 860px;
    padding: 10px 50px 20px 50px;
    background: transparent url("../images/bg-content.png");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

Alternatively, as a quick fix you could overwrite the styles for the captcha, although this is really not an ideal solution as the `!important` declaration will then cause these to override any further styles to these elements.

```
#recaptcha_widget_div,
#recaptcha_widget_div div {
    width: auto !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    background: none !important;
}

#recaptcha_widget_div a {
    font-size: 1.0em !important;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. As you can probably tell I have no idea what i'm doing with CSS. Do you have any good web resources that gives a good introduction? I will slowly try and be more specific with my style selectors.
In the meantime, with the quick fix, i copied and pasted it into my CSS and it hasn't quite worked, is there anything else i need to do?

Thanks again!

Comment: @user3894741 Definitely the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). You seem to have a basic understanding so try this article on CSS best practices: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS. Avoid W3Schools.com as their tutorials really are not the best.

Comment: @user3894741 As for my code not working, I notice in your CSS file you also have the code from the other answer after mine, I would suggest removing this as it will be overriding the styles in my code as it is after my CSS in the code, otherwise it could be the styles are being overridden somewhere else, in which case you can add `!important` after the CSS value to ensure this doesn't happen. I have updated my answer to reflect this, although I would highly recommend trying the other solutions of making your parent selectors more specific first.

Comment: Hello again, that website looks really good, thanks. Such clear explanations. So with the !important added my page is taking shape, just need to override the fonts which i tried by adding some extra bits to your code but it hasn't worked. Still some padding issues and bottom border as well unfortunately. Sorry to be a pain.

Comment: @user3894741 Again, to completely get rid of this problem you will need to edit your styles not to use the `div div` global selector, otherwise you will constantly be adding fixes that could break other code. The problem you are describing is because the `a` in the captcha is inheriting a font-size of `36px` from somewhere else in your CSS, you will also need to override this, I have edited my code again to give you an example.

Comment: Thank you very much I'm slowly getting this. It looks great now. How did you know that recaptcha uses the style selector
    #recaptcha_widget_div?

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'inspect element' feature of your browser to find a unique selector for the recaptcha element. Create a specific css rule for that element, and override the part that is making your display ugly.

Try this css:

```
#recaptcha_privacy{font-family:helvetica, sans-serif!important;font-size:8pt!important;
#recaptcha_widget_div{padding:0!important;}
```

The !important may or may not be needed. You can move the recaptcha to the right, to appear where you need it, by adding margin-left to the css for recaptcha_widget_div. However you may have to handle that part differently depending on the width of the user's viewport.

Comment: Thank you, would it help if i gave you an address of the site...    http://jamesrobinharper.co.uk/donate.php  http://jamesrobinharper.co.uk/css/style.css  (sorry for all the messy messy amateur code)

Comment: I have edited my answer, please try the css I added.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. So i just copied and pasted that straight into my CSS. Is there anything else i need to do? It's not quite working at the moment.